# Installing an asp application on a dnn server

Tags: asp.net, aspx

I created a registration db/web application in C# for some workshops.  The organization requesting is hosted on a DotNetNuke server.  What changes do I need to make to the web.config so it can run under the site.  Currently when I try to go to a page it get an error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you didn't turn your folder into an asp.net application.  Check with your support. They should be able to fix this easily.